# Probability of $k$ collisions

Tags: probability, combinatorics, balls-in-bins, hash-function

Say we have $m$ buckets. We select a random bucket and put a ball in it, we repeat this $n$ times. In the end what is the probability of having at least one bucket with exactly $k$ balls?

I have tried several approaches, the closest I got is this. The probability of putting first $k$ balls into that cell is $\frac1{m^k}$ and not putting the rest of the balls is $\left( 1 - \frac1{m} \right)^{n-k}$. We have $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}n\\k\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ such configurations, i.e. a cell getting $k$ balls and not having the rest, hence the final probability is:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}n\\k\end{pmatrix} \frac1{m^k} \left( 1 - \frac1{m} \right)^{n-k}
$$

We have $m$ such cells, so the final probability is:
$$
m\begin{pmatrix}n\\k\end{pmatrix} \frac1{m^k} \left( 1 - \frac1{m} \right)^{n-k}
$$

I have implemented a simulation where I simulate the procedure million times and report the results. For small probabilities simulation and the expression produces close results. However for particular values they don't coincide.

I suspect that the expression above needs more terms, but for small probabilities those terms tend to be very small and could be discarded to approximate.

**EDIT** Problem solved, see the answer below.

Comment: Do you want exactly $k$ balls or least $k$ balls? A single bucket with $k$ balls or at least one bucket with $k$ balls? Any bucket, or a specific bucket?

Comment: At least one bucket with exactly $k$ balls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with probability of putting $k$ balls into one box and generalizing to $m$ box followed by inclusion-exclusion principle I got the expression below.

$$
\sum^{\lfloor \frac{n}{k} \rfloor}_{i=1} (-1)^{i+1} \binom{m}{i} \left[ \prod^{i-1}_{j=0} \binom{n-jk}{k} \right] \left( \frac1{m} \right)^{ik}  \left( \frac{m-i}{m} \right)^{n-ik}
$$

Compared it with experimental results, they coincided perfectly. More details [here](http://www.anlak.com/2015/01/probability-of-k-collisions.html).

Answer (score 2):

Your approach makes the error of "double counting": a configuration that has $k$ balls in the first bucket and in the second is counted twice. You could try by using inclusion-exclusion, but the result would probably be complicated.

A simple approximation, it should work for $m\to \infty$ , $n/m \to t$ constant

The model can be approximated as $m$ iid Poisson vars, with mean $t=n/m$. Then the desired probability is

$$ P \approx 1 - \left(1- e^{-t} \frac{t^k}{k!}\right)^m $$